# Out of memory VBA error which unables me to even open a developer window(alt + F11)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a strange problem, when I try to open developer window in Excel I have a yellow prompt "Out of memory". I have changed registry editor 
values from 738 to 1024 ( I have 64 bit system version), but it doesn't help at all. So my main problem is that i cant even open a macro developer windows in excel, how i can fix that?
Ps: I would like to mention that i have plenty of free memory in my PC.

Comment: The only thing coming to my mind is that your Excel app has some add-in installed, this add-in is triggered when the developer tab is selected, and that code goes out of memory. Have you tried disabling all add-ins from your Excel and see if you can still not open it?

Comment: I've got MySQL for excel connector and I disconeccted it but it is still not working :

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I received the same error but it started with PowerPiviot and after a few days even opening excel would trigger the error. I disabled addons, changed settings, nothing worked and the problem actually got worse. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling office 365 and that fixed the problem.

P.S.

In my situation the problem also occurred very shortly after upgrading OS from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Don't know if that applies in your situation but I thought I would add that note just in case it's useful.